# target img class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I know I can write:

```
 $('.2020').css("padding", "20px");
```

But how do I write it like:

```
 $('.a').children('img').children('.2020').css("padding", "20px");

 <div class"a">
 <img class="2020" src="img/swatch/2020.jpg" >
 <img class="2021" src="img/swatch/2021.jpg" >
 <img class="2022" src="img/swatch/2022.jpg" >
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ssRYk/

Comment: Invalid: <div class"a">

Comment: Make sure you do not get the children of the children.

Comment: Also you need to close `img` tags: `<img class="2020" src="img/swatch/2020.jpg" />` etc

Comment: @Dom, you do not have to close them.

Comment: @epascarello I know, but it is good habit to get into. Probably should've added `side note:`. my mistake!

Comment: @Dom, and [html5 they are just there for show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle and code above both have an error, it is missing the `=` in your `class="a"`

You are saying look for all elements that have the class a. Than look for children that are images. Now look for images that have a child with the class 2021. Since images can not have children, that code would never return anything.

You can combine the two children statements with one selector instead of doing multiple actions.

```
$('.a').children('img.2021').css("padding", "5px");
```

You could also write it without the children in just one selector

```
$('.a > img.2021').css("padding", "5px");
```

The alternative is filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `$('.a').children('img').children('.2020')` tries to find elements with class `2020` which is inside an `img` element which is inside an element with class `a`.

Ex

```
<div class="a">
    <img src="img/swatch/2020.jpg" >
        <span class="2020"></span>
    </img>
</div>
```

But in your case the `img` element has the class attribute, so you have two choices either concatenate the `img` and `.2020` selector like `.children('img.2020')` or find the `img` elements using `.children('img')` and filter elements with class within that set using `.filter('.2020')`

If you want to retain the same structure, then you can

```
$('.a').children('img').filter('.2021').css("padding", "5px");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q6UFK/)